# How to proxy to a web server on a node that can make outgoing connections but has no accessible IP, without root?

Tags: linux, firewall, port-forwarding

Not sure if this is the right StackExchange site to ask (I mainly frequent SO), but since you guys are server admin experts hopefully you'll find it relevant!

Some context: I'm currently trying to run services like IPython Notebook servers on compute nodes of an academic cluster running [Open Grid Scheduler](http://gridscheduler.sourceforge.net/), and be able to access them from my laptop. Unfortunately, the nodes seem to be configured/firewalled so that they can't accept any outside connections (except the Scheduler interface itself, through which I can rsh in), and navigating the bureaucracy to change this is doomed to failure. You can't even ping the compute nodes from another node in the cluster.

Ideally, I'd set up dynamic port forwarding on the shell I'm using to connect to the compute node. But the shell used by default in the Scheduler is RSH, not SSH, and my understanding is that RSH doesn't support port forwarding. And asking the bureaucracy to change this is, again, a no-go.

So for a workaround, I'd imagine a forwarding program running on an external server (one that's accessible from anywhere, say an EC2 instance), that the locked-down compute node would connect to with a long-running TCP session, via a specialized client. Then, if I wanted to connect to port 8080 on the compute node, I'd use the external server as a SOCKS proxy server or a VPN server, and the external server would forward my commands to the compute node client program, which would in turn forward commands to localhost:8080.

Do a forwarding program and client like this exist, or a simpler solution? If not, should I write one? Am I overlooking something obvious that would make this impossible?

Thanks!

Comment: Are these compute nodes meant to be used interactively (e.g. ipython notebook), or are they intended for batch processing?

Answer (score 0):

You could schedule a job that starts up [autossh](http://www.harding.motd.ca/autossh/) and uses it to establish a tunnel to an external server. Then, you could connect from your laptop via that external server. That said, I wouldn't recommend this as it is likely to get you in trouble with "the bureaucracy". I'm sure it's frustrating to not be able to use these compute resources the way you would like, but you should understand that the typical HPC cluster is a resource that is designed to meet a certain narrow set of needs. It might not be possible for that resource to meet your needs as well.